# Hard Drive Partitioning?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I am not a basic user of computers, but frankly I have never done a partition of a hard drive. But I decided to shrink the only HD in the computer by 25GB for Ubuntu, however I realized that Ubuntu will partition the HD. However, I am stuck with a 25GB partition that I can not use, at least I think so... Can I use the partition when installing Ubuntu (version 9.10) or can I make the partition apart of the rest of the drive again? When I try to delete it, Windows 7 (the only OS at the moment) prompts me stating that it is an extended partition and will be inaccessible if I do so.

Help?

Comment: I am a bit confused as so what you're asking.  Can you post your partition table?  The simplest way to do this is from linux: `fdisk -l`

Answer (score 0):

You can do select that partition while installing - just don't pick either automatic partitioning method. Alternately, you could just format it as a new partition from disc management in windows, or some parted varient in linux.